# EXC_BAD_ACCESS when using string declared in header file

Tags: iphone, string, exc-bad-access, header-files

I've declared a string in my header file like so:

```
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString *resultOfHash;
```

I call my getHash method like so:

```
 NSString *hash = [self getHash];
```

My getHash method is:

```
-(NSString *) getHash
{
//Get username form Keychain
KeychainItemWrapper *keyChain = [[KeychainItemWrapper alloc]    initWithIdentifier:KeyChainName accessGroup:nil];
username = [keyChain objectForKey:(__bridge id)kSecAttrAccount];

//get token from NSUserDefauls
NSString *token = [[NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults]objectForKey:@"Token"];

NSString *toHash = [[username stringByAppendingString:HashExtra] stringByAppendingString:token];

const char *s = [toHash cStringUsingEncoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];

NSData *keyData = [NSData dataWithBytes:s length:strlen(s)];

uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};

CC_SHA512(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);

NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];

//convert to string
resultOfHash = [out description];
//App crashed out above

// get rid of unwanted characters
resultOfHash = [resultOfHash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@" " withString:@""];
resultOfHash = [resultOfHash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@"<" withString:@""];
resultOfHash = [resultOfHash stringByReplacingOccurrencesOfString:@">" withString:@""];

//log to make sure it works
NSLog(@"hash is: %@", resultOfHash);

return resultOfHash;
}
```

My code crashes out at the line: ResultOfHash = [out description]; but I'm not sure why.

When I use a local variable the conversion works fine but then I cannot return the local variable from the getHash method. Example:

Replace ResultOfHash = [out description];

with

```
NSString *local = [out description];
return local;
```

and the conversion works fine and when I debug line by line, the debugger will go to my closing bracket on my method and then produce the EXC_BAD_ACCESS error.

I've tried running NSZombie but that didn't find anything at all.

Any help in trying to sort this out would be greatly appreciated.

Comment: did you have synthesize the string  resultOfHash ???

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think the problem is here:

```
uint8_t digest[CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH] = {0};
CC_SHA512(keyData.bytes, keyData.length, digest);
NSData *out = [NSData dataWithBytes:digest length:CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH];
```

You are using `CC_SHA512`, but only allocate array of size `CC_SHA1_DIGEST_LENGTH`, which is smaller and will lead to the buffer overrunning.

To correct this, you should use `CC_SHA512_DIGEST_LENGTH` instead.

Comment: Spot on Tia. This code was originally setup for SHA512 and I converted to SHA1 but missed that line. When I changed it to SHA1 and changed resultsofHash to NSMutableString, the code worked. Thanks for that

Answer (score 1):

Have a look at [the answer in this question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417893/encrypted-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-obj-c). Try converting to `NSString` using

```
[NSString *local = [[[NSString alloc] initWithData:out encoding:NSASCIIStringEncoding];
```

I haven't tested this code with this encoding, but it's similar to something I already use.

Update -

I corrected an error in the code above. I somehow left the method signiture out in a distracted copy and paste.

Comment: Thanks for pointing this out Draco. I didn't know using the description part of NSData was wrong. I'll change that.

Answer (score 0):

It's crashing because `out` is unretained. You should add retain:

```
resultOfHash = [[out description] retain];
```

or use retained property:

```
self.resultOfHash = [out description];
```

Check this, it should be work.

Comment: The author seems to be using ARC.

Comment: In the fact, he didn't write about it.

Answer (score 0):

You probably need to use an `NSMutableString`.