# ios - encrypt/decrypt NSString

Tags: ios, encryption

> **Possible Duplicate:**
>   [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

What is the best way to encrypt or decrypt `NSString` using a custom key?

Is there any good library for that ?

Comment: Describe your use case please. There are many forms of encryption, and many of them are only applicable under certain conditions.

Comment: The use case is that i'm trying to encrypt NSString and save it in a database. In the future i'll want to decrypt it.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Take a look at this question:

[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

And take a look at this library:

https://github.com/dev5tec/FBEncryptor

However, one note on this library: It uses some bad practices. So, if security is important for you I would recommend read up a little bit more regarding that and choose another code which does encryption (or write it on your own).

Comment: Good answer. I also use this one: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1417893/encrypted-nsdata-to-nsstring-in-obj-c