# AES128 Encryption at Java server - Decryption of Files on IOS

Tags: iphone, objective-c, ios, security, encryption

I have a file which is AES128 encrypted coming from Java server into my application. I need to decrypt these files using AES128 decryption in my application. Any suggestions on how to go about this? Any libraries/algorithms supporting decryption of files and content on IOS - and - encryption on the server-side (JAVA).

I would also like to know all types of encryptions that can be decrypted on IOS

Thanks in advance.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/2774239/help-for-aes-128-bit-algorithm-i-want-to-encrypt-it

Comment: What?  Where are you going to put the key?  Why are you trying to encrypt this information?

Comment: @Rook I've  audios, videos & images that come encrypted into my app from java server. All the assets(A,V,I) will have same key associated with them. Am i clear now, Rook?

Comment: @Pranav OK so then send them plain text?  An attacker has more control over the device than you do,  there is no place to keep a secret on the device there for encryption is completely useless to you.

Comment: @rook Not Clear can you plz explain more clearly.

Comment: @Pranav I'm sorry this is so obvious.  If you put your secret key in the binary it can be decompiled and then the attacker can decrypt your files.  This is not a problem that cryptography can solve,  period end of story.  This is a problem with your business model.