# iPhone: Encrypt Nsstring using AES 128 and Decrypt

Tags: iphone, encryption, aes

I am new to Encryption/ Decryption. I want to encrypt a NSString variable value using key. Also I want to decrypt the encrypted data . I want to apply AES -128 Algorithm.

Please suggest sample code or useful link.

Comment: Just an FYI if u use encryption in an app it makes submission a bit tricky but you probably know that already. Wish I could answer your question.

Comment: possible duplicate of [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Comment: @Rupesh 
I wanna do same .
I am receiving string of and key from server and want to decrypt it using AES !28.

What should i do.

I search a lot but all links that i found dont have the exact answer include the apple official one.

http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/CryptoExercise/Listings/Classes_CryptoCommon_h.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40008019-Classes_CryptoCommon_h-DontLinkElementID_7

Comment: @Rupesh 
Hey Brother did you find answer to your question.???

Answer (score 1):

I found this through a Google search on the terms `aes nsstring site:stackoverflow.com`:

> [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Comment: It's probably not too much different. Instead of the answer being handed to you without you doing any work, you could use it as a basis to learn about AES and about the other functions you would use.