# In App Purchase Resources Security

Tags: iphone, security, resources, bundle, in-app-purchase

Hi I am setting up in app purchase where user can buy different Sounds. Once bought, he can play those sounds in the App. The Sound files are all present in my Resources Folder and I just keep a record(in a plist) of the files that have been purchased. 
No If I right click on the IAP file and see its content I can see the Resources, hence any one can have those sounds without actually buying them.
Is there a protected Bundle or something?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You could encrypt each of those files and when they are purchased, decrypt them and make them available for use.

Below is an `NSData` category that makes it simple to encrypt data in iOS:

.h:

```
#import <Foundation/Foundation.h>

@interface NSData (DataCategory)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;

@end
```

.m

```
#import "NSDataCategory.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (DataCategory)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end
```

Code used from [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone).

Comment: Hi thanks. I think Encrypting and Decrypting back files is a good Idea but for that I will need to work encrypt every sound file. Which will take much long time and effort. But thanks anyways. i like your approach.

Answer (score -2):

You could always flip some of the bits in the sound files, then flip them back once they're purchased from the app.  Depending on how much you change, you can either corrupt the file headers or completely mangle the audio until you correct them.