# iOS 5: Data encryption AES-256 EncryptWithKey: not found

Tags: iphone, ios, ios5

Question is about iOS5 application.  I have a view controller where I have some UITextFields.
I would like to encrypt data using AES-256.

In fact, I don't know what are the prerequisite packages that I have to add to do encryption and decryption.  I have gone trough other posts but too much explanation messed it up.

Kindly let me know what and all packages, header files  I have to include to encrypt data using AES-256

Chandra

Comment: Check this out: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: @Adam: Packages and header files to include are not listed.

Comment: This answer provides complete solution: http://stackoverflow.com/a/5078432/730701

Answer (score 39, accepted):

refer a following category.

FAQ: What is a category?

> In short, Cocoa API to add the method. briefly expand class.

More information,

> [CustomizingExistingClasses](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/Cocoa/Conceptual/ProgrammingWithObjectiveC/CustomizingExistingClasses/CustomizingExistingClasses.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40011210-CH6-SW2)
>
> [Category](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/General/Conceptual/DevPedia-CocoaCore/Category.html)

File-New-Cocoa Touch - Objective-C category

If you want to use a category, your class add a  #import"NSData+Encryption.h"

[image]

[image]

//NSData+Encryption.h

```
@interface NSData (Encryption)
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key;
@end
```

---

//NSData+Encryption.m

```
#import "NSData+Encryption.h"
#import <CommonCrypto/CommonCryptor.h>

@implementation NSData (Encryption)
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
    
    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    
    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    
    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }
    
    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES256+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)
    
    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
    
    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];
    
    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or 
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);
    
    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES256,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);
    
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }
    
    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
@end
```

Comment: is it smart, or is there a way to do this directly with nsstrings, with no nsdata involved?

Comment: I can't say enough how impressed I am with this solution.