# iOS and .NET password encryption

Tags: c#, ios, objective-c, encryption, active-directory

I have been working on building an iOS app to be used internally inside the company I work for. The way the user logs into the app is through the use of Active Directory (AD). The code I have for checking credentials via AD is as follows:

```
private bool ADAuthentication(string username, string password)
    {
        using (PrincipalContext pc = new PrincipalContext(ContextType.Domain, "Domain Name"))
        {
            return pc.ValidateCredentials(username, password);
        }
    }
```

The problem I have is that this method requires a clear text password and I am not about to send that kind of password across a cellphone network or unknown wifi connection.

What I am looking for is an encryption/decryption algorithm that I can encrypt the password on an iOS device, send it to our server, decrypt it, and pass it to the above method to verify AD credentials.

So far I have investigated MD5 (which we already use in another application) and several open source BlowFish algorithms(Here is the [link](http://www.schneier.com/blowfish-download.html) and a [link](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13507384/how-to-implement-blowfish-algorithm-in-ios?answertab=active#tab-top) for how to do BlowFish in iOS). I have also done research via google looking for a solution and have not found much relating to what I need (but I could have missed something)

Any code, links, or advice in either Objective-c or C# would be greatly appreciated since I have been at this for 2 days with little-to-no progress being made. I am open to almost anything at this point.

Comment: Where is this code executed? At the client side? Or rather you have an application server that the ios application talks to?

Comment: @WiktorZychla The code above is executed on our servers through a web service.

Comment: If the connection is over SSL, then you don't need to worry about the cell network/wifi connection you're on. It'll be more secure than any homebrew crypto scheme.

Comment: @mfanto Thats what I was thinking, but my boss wanted me to find some form of encryption for it. Now they are telling me SSL will work just fine.

Comment: SSL is encryption. It's designed to protect the underlying transport, and will prevent snooping, tampering with messages, replay attacks, among other things. It's also universally supported, extensively studied, and required for compliance by a lot of standards.