# How To Encrypt something in .NET and Decrypt it in Objective C

Tags: .net, objective-c, macos, encryption, cryptography

I am trying to create an application that runs on OS X that can read a file that was encrypted in .NET on Windows.  I have been searching all over the internet for an example, but I haven't found any.  The best I was able to find was this:

[iOS and .NET password encryption](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/14445098/ios-and-net-password-encryption)

However no one was actually answered the question.  Has anyone solved this?

Comment: If nobody has answered your question, that's probably your question is maybe too vague?  It sounds like you are asking somebody to write code or run a search for you instead of getting help with actual lines of code that don't quite run.

Comment: Also different ciphers have dramatically different requirements, etc. There's not one universally "blessed" encryption mechanism, so what's entailed is going to vary wildly depending on the cipher, the key exchange mechanism, etc.

Answer (score 2):

The simplest in your case (if you don't want to deal with cryptography) would be to take some PGP library and use passphrase-based (no openpgp keys) encryption. You can use key-based encryption as well, of course, if you need that.

Comment: As per the old adage, PGP for data at rest and TLS for data in transit.