# How to save RSA publicKey/privateKey NOT in Keychain

Tags: ios, rsa, keychain

i have a question about saving Keys within iOS applications.

Is there any way to save the public/private Key of an RSA-certificate within an app, not to save/store this in the iOS keychain.
Maybe someone tried this out before?

I found something similar with username and password. Its called "Keychainwrapper". There the app saves the login credentials within the app. Does this work for me with private/public keys?

Hopefully someone can help me.

Best regards,

Andi

Comment: Why not keychain? You can store arbitrary data in username/password field, so that should work for public/private keys. If you really want to store it within app, use `NSUserDefaults` or directly write to plist. You really need to elaborate on your requirements. Also, `keychainwrapper` sounds like a wrapper for keychain.. :)

Comment: Well, it's a requirement, to store this not in keychain :). Thank you

Comment: If your requirement is that the certificate has to be stored within the app. I would suggest using the RSA Certificate in the pkcs5 format. Is this certificate delivered with the app or are you going to download it? Problem in this scenario is that you have to protect the pkcs5 password.

Comment: the certificates will be generated within the app and should not be stored in the keychain. the certificates are used for encrypting and decrypting data.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Since you have to store only public and private key and not the whole certificate, can not use the internal keychain and the keys are generated on the device it would be sufficient if you save your public and private key in the NSUserDefaults:

```
NSUserDefaults *prefs = [NSUserDefaults standardUserDefaults];
//saving the data
[prefs setObject"<your public key data>" forKey:@"PublicKey"];
[prefs setObject"<your private key data>" forKey:@"PrivateKey"];

//reading the data
NSString *publicKey = [prefs stringForKey:@"PublicKey"];
NSString *privateKey = [prefs stringForKey:@"PrivateKey"];
```

This store is rather insecure, so I would suggest that you encrypt your data like this: [iOS 5: Data encryption AES-256 EncryptWithKey: not found](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/11482470/ios-5-data-encryption-aes-256-encryptwithkey-not-found). Be aware, that symmetric encryption is not secure if you store the key in your application! You should use some user input to generate the key.

Hope this helps.

Comment: Yes, thank you very much. User input is in mind, but wasn't a question in this case :)