# I don't understand this instruction. (Inserting adapted code)

Tags: ios

I am newbie for iOS.  I try to encrypt string with AES256. I follow instruction in this question :
[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

I confuse to understand **yellow marked words.**

[image]

Previous, I copy above codes. But I get error...

[image]

Why I can get error ? **Because I don't insert adapted code that have been marked by yellow ink at top picture. That yellow marked words linked to here :** http://pastie.org/426530#

**MY MAIN QUESTIONS IS : I CONFUSE TO INSERT ADAPTED CODE IN TOP ANSWER IN THIS LINK** [AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

**I don't understand how to copy source code inside that link. I doubt I just create class NSData. From what I know, NSData is class from C-Objective libraries**

Comment: What are the errors?

Comment: Please, read first before voting. I confuse to follow instruction

Comment: "Adapted" in this case just means "modified." The writer is just indicating that the code used is not precisely the same as originally written. This answer, however, is referring to a very insecure piece of code (not listed in your description). It is a terrible way to encrypt data.

Comment: Oh, I am new in learning encryption. How to insert/modify the adapted code ? The adapted code is http://pastie.org/426530#

Comment: @WrightsCS links the instructions below. But keep in mind that this is very insecure code and should not be used for anything requiring significant encryption. For a full explanation of the problems with this code, see http://robnapier.net/aes-commoncrypto

Answer (score 0):

There is source code after the first `return` in that `main` function. `@autoreleasepool` is not a conditional; code within the block will execute 100% of the time.

Answer (score 0):

Seems to me like this code had a class category of NSData that contained a custom method for `AES256EncryptWithKey:`, `AES256DecryptWithKey:`.

See this answer https://stackoverflow.com/a/11483134/171206 on SO that shows you how to implement this.