# Can I encrypt a TSV file within an iPad app?

Tags: objective-c, xcode, encryption

My iPad app currently saves user input data in a TSV (tab separated values) file. At the end, the user emails this file out. The problem now is that I have to abide by certain policies because the information is sensitive. Is there a way to encrypt the TSV file before it is emailed?

Note: I've decided to EMAIL this TSV file because I have found NO other way to get this file onto a computer from the iPad's sandbox. If there is a better way than email, I will gladly implement it (EXCEPT using iTunes to download the app's sandbox data, which does NOT abide by the policies).

THANKS AHEAD OF TIME!

Comment: Beside of the fact you can encryption for both ways, why is emailing better than using iTunes? In the last case, your data will stay at your computer.

Answer (score 0):

[Use iFunBox](http://www.google.com/url?sa=t&rct=j&q=&esrc=s&source=web&cd=1&ved=0CEMQFjAA&url=http://www.i-funbox.com/&ei=8rsaUO_JMoXY2AXWh4H4Aw&usg=AFQjCNF9USijQCeC-BUxnX0jN34pGFQamw). You can copy files directly from an iOS device. No jailbreak required.

Answer (score 0):

To encrypt your file, you can use any encryption algorythm for text, like [AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

Then, to send the data to your server, you can post it using a web service. [ASIHTTPRequest](http://allseeing-i.com/ASIHTTPRequest/) can help for this.

Good luck with that!