# String encryption in RubyMotion

Tags: ios, encryption, aes, blowfish, rubymotion

I'm trying to encrypt strings in RubyMotion - ideally AES but weaker/older cyphers such as Blowfish should do just fine.

So far I have failed at compiling a couple of pods: RNCrypto and CommonCrypto.

Suggestions? Anyone else tried these pods?

Thank you,
Adrian

Comment: This is available through Apple's frameworks, please see this question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone (which Rubymotion has access to all of them as far as I know, this is pretty simple just try it in the terminal after launching an app)

Comment: Seems like a good suggestion, I will try it.

Comment: It would be better than using a pod for simple string encryption, don't want to bloat your program with pods you don't need.

Comment: Unfortunately the code doesn't port nicely to RubyMotion, I get an undefined method `AES256EncryptWithKey' for #<NSConcreteMutableData error.

Comment: for your CommonCrypto pod, are you including Security framework in your rake file? ex:  app.frameworks << 'Security'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here's the necessary process if you currently want to use CommonCrypto pod:

- make sure to include the pod in your Rakefile or perform the equivalent Bundler ritual
- don't forget to include *app.frameworks << 'Security'* in the Rakefile as well
- then go to vendor/Pods/CommonCrypto and delete the file example.m

Congratulations, you're all set!

Here's a quick (and dirty) sample:

```
iv = 'init_vector_here'
key = 'key_here'
plainText = 'This is plain text'

plainData = plainText.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
ivData = iv.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)
keyData = key.dataUsingEncoding(NSUTF8StringEncoding)

status = NIL
result = plainData.dataEncryptedUsingAlgorithm(0, key: keyData, initializationVector: ivData, options: 0, error: status) # 0 = AES128
p result.base64EncodedString
```

For Base64 encoding you have to include the 'NSData+Base64' pod.

Thank you @AwDogsGo2Heaven and @Jamon Holmgren for your helpful suggestions!

Answer (score 3):

If you're having trouble compiling CocoaPods, make sure you run a `rake clean`. CocoaPods should work fine with RubyMotion as far as I know.

EDIT: Since the OP hasn't posted his solution as the answer, I'll post it here:

> RNCryptor doesn't build for iOS6, and there's a pull for ARC compatibility but not yet integrated in the pod.
>
> As for CommonCrypto, it has an example.m file showcasing its capabilities. This example.m includes a main function which clashes with the one created by RubyMotion. By deleting it, I've managed to make it compile successfully.

Comment: Tried that, no luck. Have you succeeded at compiling one of the pods mentioned here? I'm using rvm with Ruby 1.9.2-p320 and all latest version for cocoapods.

Comment: I did a `rake` with those pods added and didn't have an issue. I didn't have them implemented anywhere, though.

Comment: try deleting the vendor folder, and raking again.

Comment: Nope. Here's what I found: RNCryptor doesn't build for iOS6, and there's a pull for ARC compatibility but not yet integrated in the pod. As for CommonCrypto, it has an example.m file showcasing its capabilities. This example.m includes a main function which clashes with the one created by RubyMotion. By deleting it, I've managed to make it compile successfully.

Comment: Sounds like you need to add this as the answer to your question.

Comment: Yep, add it and mark it as an answer so future readers can easily find it.

Comment: I was out at a conference and just got back. I'm adding the answer together with a basic code sample.