# Can I send a URL Scheme to my App by texting someone?

Tags: iphone, ios, objective-c, sms

Basically the problem is my app has some very specific server settings that will change from store location to store location.

Instead of me telling the client over the phone what to set their phone as.

Server IP:
Username:
Password:
Service IP:

etc.

I'd like to be able to send a text message to their iDevice witha  URL Scheme that they will tap and will automatically activate my app.

Can I send a message like this?

"And apparently I need 30 characters :P to be able to post..."

Comment: I don't think this question is clear enough, this is by far my understanding. You need to send an SMS to a phone, and that message will have a link that will launch your app and change the store location for them. Correct?

Comment: Yes. I will send an sms which will launch my iOS app and process the URL scheme by changing the in app settings automatically for them.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

This is quite simple. I think what you want to implement is what Apple called a "custom URL scheme"

You can find it in [this](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/iphone/conceptual/iphoneosprogrammingguide/iPhoneAppProgrammingGuide.pdf) Apple documentation at page 122.

First, your application registers to the system at install telling it that you will handle this URL scheme, for example, "myapp://"

Then, you simply text it to your client.

Comment: You might want to encrypt some of your information with some algorithm, here's one that looks pretty nice.

http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: I just tried it and I am able to launch my app via a text message so the concept will work. I will also look into the encoding part.