# Decrypt encrypted string in iOS using MD5 algorithm

Tags: ios, objective-c, nsstring, md5, encryption

Basically I want to **encrypt and decrypt** password in `iOS`.

So far I have used following method to encrypt password

```
- (NSString *) stringFromMD5{

    if(self == nil || [self length] == 0)
        return nil;

    const char *value = [self UTF8String];

    unsigned char outputBuffer[CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH];
    CC_MD5(value, strlen(value), outputBuffer);

    NSMutableString *outputString = [[NSMutableString alloc] initWithCapacity:CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH * 2];
    for(NSInteger count = 0; count < CC_MD5_DIGEST_LENGTH; count++){
        [outputString appendFormat:@"%02x",outputBuffer[count]];
    }

    return [outputString autorelease];
}
```

This is using `MD5` hash to encrypt string.

**Question:**

1. As I read somewhere it is not possible to decrypt `MD5` hash. Is this really true  ? If no then can you please guide me on decryption using `MD5`.
2. If first one is not possible then are there any other alternatives to both encrypt and decrypt `NSString` in `iOS`.

I really welcome your suggestions on this please.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

1. Yes, it is true. MD5 is a one-way hash function. You can compare two MD5-hashed strings to check if the original plain inputs were equal.
2. Take a look at the AES encryption for NSString discussion [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone).

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is not an encryption algorithm, it's a hash function. Unless you manage to brute force it, there's no way to have the original data back from the hash.

Have a look at OpenSSL instead.

Comment: +1 for obvious note about what md5 is, but -1 for `Unless you manage to brute force it`

Comment: @H2CO3 can you please guide me more on brute force and OpenSSL ?

Comment: @Bhargavi Don't bother with brute force, instead use an algorithm that is designed to be reversible.  One of the leading standards today is AES.  There is plenty of information out there on how to use it on iOS.

Comment: @WebnetMobile I'm sure if I hadn't put in the comment about brute force, you would have complained stating that "'you can't get back the data' is not technically true"...

Answer (score 3):

MD5 is a cryptographic hash function. You can't decrypt the generated hash.

Comment: Do you know any  alternatives to both encrypt and decrypt ?