# Partial encryption using AES - IOS application

Tags: ios, ios5, encryption, aes, encryption-asymmetric

I would like to apply the encryption & decryption technique in one my downloading concept. I want to do the partial encryption using AES 256. Is it possible to do it? is it have any algorithms available for partial encryption&decryption.

Please suggest ideas.

Partial Encryption : it means i dont want to encrypt the full content of the file.It will do the encryption for some specified part of file.(like 10% or 20%) or some junks of file content. basically , I dont want to do the encryption to the entire content
THanks.

Comment: What do you mean by "Partial encryption" ? Can you please elaborate it ?

Comment: Bhargavi,, please look on my edited post.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I'm not aware of any algorithms that offer "partial encryption" functionality. Instead, I think you'll need to take charge of separating out the bytes you wish to encrypt and pass that through [standard AES encryption code](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone).

Comment: I used the described technique when I realized that big files were too slow for mobile devices to decrypt efficiently.