# Using soap with IOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, xml, soap

I am planning to use [**WSLD2OBJC**](https://code.google.com/p/wsdl2objc/) in an enterprise application to consume SOAP based services. But last update for wsdl2objc was on 2010.

1. Is **wsdl2objc** safe to use in an enterprise app?
2. Is there any other reliable components to use for soap parsing?
3. or can I use plain XML request with `NSXMLParse` for my needs?

Comment: do you plan to use .NET, PHP or ruby in backend? Why you want to use SOAP instead of REST?

Comment: the back end is in .NET.

Answer (score 2):

First and foremost, WSLD2OBJC is too bloated to be used

1) In general, SOAP itself is not safe if the message is not encrypted. Considering this SOAP body from **someSOAPmethod** if you use attribute `[WebMethod]` in .NET with SOAP v1.0:

```
POST /WebService/Common.asmx HTTP/1.1
Host: localhost
Content-Type: text/xml; charset=utf-8
Content-Length: length
SOAPAction: "http://example.com/someSOAPmethod"
<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?>
<soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\">
 <soap:Body>
  <SomeSOAPmethod xmlns=\"http://example.com/\">
   <encryptedMessage>%@</encryptedMessage> //<-- this is vary, depends on your parameter
  </SomeSOAPmethod>
 </soap:Body>
</soap:Envelope>
```

the %@ must be pass with encryped data to secure SOAP. You can use whatever type of encryption but I prefer [AES](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone). To secure even more add HTTPS connection (RSA encryption).

2) You can built your own parsing instead using WSLD2OBJC. From example of **someSOAPmethod**.

```
-(NSMutableURLRequest *)encapsulateSOAP:(NSString *)encryptedMessage withSoapMethod:(NSString *)soapMethod andBaseURL:(NSURL *)baseURL
{

    NSString* soapMessage = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"<?xml version=\"1.0\" encoding=\"utf-8\"?><soap:Envelope xmlns:xsi=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema-instance\" xmlns:xsd=\"http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema\" xmlns:soap=\"http://schemas.xmlsoap.org/soap/envelope/\"><soap:Body><%@ xmlns=\"http://example.com/\"><encryptedMessage>%@</encryptedMessage></%@></soap:Body></soap:Envelope>", soapMethod, encryptedMessage, soapMethod];


    NSString* msgLength = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%d", [soapMessage length]];

    NSMutableURLRequest* theRequest = [NSMutableURLRequest requestWithURL:baseURLl];
    [theRequest addValue:@"text/xml; charset=utf-8" forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Type"];
    [theRequest addValue:[NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@%@", @"http://example.com/", soapMethod ] forHTTPHeaderField:@"SOAPAction"];
    [theRequest setHTTPMethod:@"POST"];
    [theRequest addValue:msgLength forHTTPHeaderField:@"Content-Length"];
    [theRequest setHTTPBody: [soapMessage dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding]];
    [theRequest setTimeoutInterval:10];

    return theRequest;
}
```

How to use above method:

```
    NSString *encryptedMessage = //some encrypted message
    NSString *soapMethod = @"someSOAPmethod";
    NSURL *baseURL = [NSURL urlWithString:@"http://example.com"];
    NSMutableURLRequest *requestQueue = [self encapsulateSOAPRequest:encryptedMessage withSoapMethod:soapMethod andBaseURL:baseURL];
    //then request using AFNetworking, ASIHTTP or your own networking library
```

3) Yes, you can use  `NSXMLParse` or any 3rd-party library that you like to bind SOAP request or  unbind SOAP response.