# 3des encryption and decryption in iOS

Tags: ios, objective-c, encryption, 3des

I am working on 3DES encryption and decryption. I have done encryption successfully. For decryption, I am using this code but not getting exact result. My encryption string is "**CHc3TsfJgYs=**" and key is "**meristem**". Please tell me what I am doing wrong?

```
 NSString *token = @"CHc3TsfJgYs=";
    NSString *key = @"meristem";

    const void *vplainText;
    size_t plainTextBufferSize;

    plainTextBufferSize = [token length];
    vplainText = (const void *) [token UTF8String];

    CCCryptorStatus ccStatus;
    uint8_t *bufferPtr = NULL;
    size_t bufferPtrSize = 0;
    size_t movedBytes ;

    bufferPtrSize = (plainTextBufferSize + kCCBlockSize3DES) & ~(kCCBlockSize3DES - 1);
    bufferPtr = malloc( bufferPtrSize * sizeof(uint8_t));
    memset((void *)bufferPtr, 0x0, bufferPtrSize);
    // memset((void *) iv, 0x0, (size_t) sizeof(iv));


    NSString *initVec = @"init Vec";
    const void *vkey = (const void *) [key UTF8String];
    const void *vinitVec = (const void *) [initVec UTF8String];

    ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                       kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                       kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                       vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                       kCCKeySizeDES,
                       NULL,// vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                       vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                       plainTextBufferSize,
                       (void *)bufferPtr,
                       bufferPtrSize,
                       &movedBytes);

    NSString *result;
    NSData *myData = [NSData dataWithBytes:(const void *)bufferPtr length:(NSUInteger)movedBytes];
    result = [myData base64Encoding];
    // result = [myDat];
    NSLog(@"dis is data %@",result);
```

Comment: What are you getting as the output? Are there any warnings or errors? It would help if you showed your encryption code too.

Comment: Visit this link, You might be get Proper solution
[Encryption and Decryption][1]


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: In which form are you getting the data from API. I am able to encrypt successfully but while decrypting the data from server I am getting  <OS_dispatch_data: data[0x1c0275f00] = { leaf, size = 442, buf = 0x105826c00 }>. I can see data is there but unable to decrypt in iOS.

Answer (score 1):

```
ccStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt,
                   kCCAlgorithm3DES,
                   kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                   vkey, //"123456789012345678901234", //key
                   kCCKeySize3DES,
                   NULL,// vinitVec, //"init Vec", //iv,
                   vplainText, //"Your Name", //plainText,
                   plainTextBufferSize,
                   (void *)bufferPtr,
                   bufferPtrSize,
                   &movedBytes);
```

you need change `kCCKeySizeDES` -> `kCCKeySize3DES`