# AES Encryption between Javascript and Objective-C

Tags: javascript, objective-c, security, encryption, aes

I am working on an ipad app with a web component which requires the data being sent from one end to the other to be encrypted.

I'm wanting to use AES encryption, but am just having trouble putting together functionality for both the javascript and objective c so i can encrypt in one and decrypt on the other using the same key.

If anyone has some code i could use or just any advice at all it would be much appreciated.

Thanks.

Comment: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: I actually already have a method for encryption on the ios side. My problem is getting it working with the javascript side as well.

Comment: there's lots of them. just make sure to encode a utf string in the non-js environment if you want interchangeability.

Comment: So if i understand correctly the important thing is just to ensure all the variables are the same on both sides right? (i.e key, key size, IV etc.)

Comment: Doing your own crypto is tough to get right. Can you not just use HTTPS to secure your connections?

Comment: Well the data is being stored by a third party on the cloud at the moment, so the encryption is really to keep it safe in there as i don't want to put too much faith into their security measures.