# How to encrypt the NSString in ios locally

Tags: ios, objective-c

I am working on the static application that means no webservices. My application contains activation page so that we need to enter text inside that textfield to validate.

```
if([textfield.text isEqualToString:@"AKS_BI"]) {
     //loading home screen
 } else {
//show alert
 }
```

For this one, I would like to encrypt the "AKS_BI" in order to hide the string while reverse engineering or Mat testing.

Can you anyone help me on this.

Comment: first decide which encryption method you want ?. refer this link for AES encryption. http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: This just moves the problem from keeping "AKS_BI" secret to keeping the encryption key secret. Who are you protecting the key from, the user or someone else?

Answer (score -1, accepted):

1. Download AES encryption files from github. [Download from here](https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC)
2. After adding these downloaded files in your project now compare ,

   ```
          if ([[AESCrypt encrypt:textfield.text password:[[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]] isEqualToString:ACTIVATION_STRING])
   ```
3. Here, ACTIVATION_STRING = hYjhuOO+GYTUBS05== .... This encrypted string needs to be created with the below syntax and make sure that remove the below syntax from code after generation of encrypted string,

   ```
      NSString *encryptedData = [AESCrypt encrypt:@"AKS_BI" password: [[NSBundle mainBundle] bundleIdentifier]];
   ```

That's it. It simple.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I have already downloaded these files. Now its working fine as expected.

Answer (score 1):

To encrypt:

```
//for best practise encrypting string length must be >=8
NSString *yourString=@"abcdefghij";

NSString *YourPasswordString = @"123456";//i've took static but you can set it dynamically
NSString *encryptPassword;

//Encrypt    
NSData *data = [YourPasswordString dataUsingEncoding: NSASCIIStringEncoding];
NSData *encryptedData = [data AESEncryptWithPassphrase:yourString];

//Encode Base 64    
[Base64 initialize];
encryptPassword = [Base64 encode:encryptedData];
```

For more details you can check [here](https://github.com/Gurpartap/AESCrypt-ObjC)

Hope this helps.

Comment: Are you sure that this method AESEncryptWithPassphrase  is available without importing third party libraries ?

Comment: NSString *yourString=@"abcdefghij";
At the time of reverse engineering and Math testing they can find this key right.

Comment: No. To find the key you need password for that. It's password protected encryption.

Answer (score 0):

You can use this library https://github.com/RNCryptor/RNCryptor.

However, you will still need to store the encryption key securely. For that I would recommend to split them up and perform some operation on them to combine.

Comment: This has just moved the problem, might as well use the advice for the encryption key for "AKS_BI".