# Replicate PHP AES 128 MyCrypt result in Objective-C

Tags: ios, objective-c, iphone, encryption

My client is using the PHP code of this page for AES encryption:

http://aesencryption.net/

The test input and key are this ones:

**Text:** 29FUER001_1464780365

**Key:** 134j31Alo1tuz

And the result in 198 bit is this:

**ywDC1DG94uSOgr+3iah+LBjiHbKY23FD**

I'm using the code posted in this question:

[AES Encryption for an NSString on the iPhone](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone)

And I have changed it to this (I think I have change it to AES 192):

```
@implementation NSData (AES256)

- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES192+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES192,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES256DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES192+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES128, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES192,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

@end 

- (NSString *) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSData *data = [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES256EncryptWithKey:key];   
    return [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
}
```

And the methods are the same:

```
- (NSString *) decryptString:(NSString *)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:ciphertext options:kNilOptions];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data AES256DecryptWithKey:key] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

But the result I'm getting is this:

**GiF2Qjd3eVJFgjVQdwa7jHQYkXMrgAp5qFfa8wGaxvE=**

If I left the code like in the answer (AES 256) and I select the 256 bit encryption in the page this are de results:

**From my code:** 9PDhJMBWOKR4oFcT43CVh49VjC6Lqyc32YGFuKWNlVY=

**From the web:** nCWrjuzD4K43yQfv1aBdGRnLTvcJy42rO/wQRY28cQU=

And this is how I'm calling the function:

```
NSLog(@"tToken String 2 %@",[self encryptString:@"29FUER001_1464780365" withKey:@"134j31Alo1tuz"]);
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Happy coding.

**EDIT 1:**

My partner that is ni charge of the Android App has made it and he is passing this parameters to his Android function:

```
Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding");
```

So I have change my code to try to get the same result but is still unsuccessful

```
- (NSData *)AES256EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 32 bytes for AES256, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);
    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

Comment: @zaphSo you think that the PHP code in the web is doing a bad encryption? I will try another page to see the results

Comment: @zaphthe PHP code is in the page that I added in the question, my Android partner has been able to make it and he is passing this parameters to his Android code Cipher cipher = Cipher.getInstance("AES/ECB/PKCS7Padding"); so I have changed my parameters to  CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
            keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
            NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
            [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
            buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
            &numBytesEncrypted);

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As Zaph mentioned the Key was only 13 bytes and it was a bad Key so at the end with a 16 bytes Key and small changes in the code everything started to work.

At the end you just have to change the Key size to kCCKeySizeAES128 and add the ECB option kCCOptionECBMode in the CCCrypt.

This is the final code:

```
@implementation NSData (AES128)

- (NSData *)AES128EncryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 16 bytes for AES128, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesEncrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCEncrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesEncrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesEncrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}

- (NSData *)AES128DecryptWithKey:(NSString *)key {
    // 'key' should be 16 bytes for AES128, will be null-padded otherwise
    char keyPtr[kCCKeySizeAES128+1]; // room for terminator (unused)
    bzero(keyPtr, sizeof(keyPtr)); // fill with zeroes (for padding)

    // fetch key data
    [key getCString:keyPtr maxLength:sizeof(keyPtr) encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];

    NSUInteger dataLength = [self length];

    //See the doc: For block ciphers, the output size will always be less than or
    //equal to the input size plus the size of one block.
    //That's why we need to add the size of one block here
    size_t bufferSize = dataLength + kCCBlockSizeAES128;
    void *buffer = malloc(bufferSize);

    size_t numBytesDecrypted = 0;
    CCCryptorStatus cryptStatus = CCCrypt(kCCDecrypt, kCCAlgorithmAES, kCCOptionPKCS7Padding | kCCOptionECBMode,
                                          keyPtr, kCCKeySizeAES128,
                                          NULL /* initialization vector (optional) */,
                                          [self bytes], dataLength, /* input */
                                          buffer, bufferSize, /* output */
                                          &numBytesDecrypted);

    if (cryptStatus == kCCSuccess) {
        //the returned NSData takes ownership of the buffer and will free it on deallocation
        return [NSData dataWithBytesNoCopy:buffer length:numBytesDecrypted];
    }

    free(buffer); //free the buffer;
    return nil;
}
```

And the methods:

```
- (NSString *) encryptString:(NSString*)plaintext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSData *data = [[plaintext dataUsingEncoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding] AES128EncryptWithKey:key];
    return [data base64EncodedStringWithOptions:kNilOptions];
}

- (NSString *) decryptString:(NSString *)ciphertext withKey:(NSString*)key {
    NSData *data = [[NSData alloc] initWithBase64EncodedString:ciphertext options:kNilOptions];
    return [[NSString alloc] initWithData:[data AES128DecryptWithKey:key] encoding:NSUTF8StringEncoding];
}
```

Happy coding.

Comment: ECB mode is insecure, see [ECB mode](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Block_cipher_mode_of_operation#Electronic_Codebook_.28ECB.29), scroll down to the Penguin.

Comment: @zaph I have already read thai is not secure, but if I don't use the hotspot that is reading my encrypted user does not work and always return Invalid User, so I have to stay with the ECB flag

Comment: Yeah, I understand: Security is over-rated, the illusion of it is good enough.

Answer (score 0):

The test result `GiF2Qjd3eVJFgjVQdwa7jHQYkXMrgAp5qFfa8wGaxvE=` is encoded in Base64 and this represents binary data of 24-bytes. It is **not possible** to get 24-bytes of output from AES. The output will always be a multiple of the block size, AES has a block size of 16-bytes.

While a 192-bit key is an option it is rarely used, in this case the actual key size is only 13-bytes.

You also need to determine if PKCS#7 (née PKCS#5) padding is being used and the mode, ECB, CBC or other such as CTR. For CBC mode (recommended) use a random iv, just prepend the iv to the encrypted data is it will be available for decryption, it does not need to be secret.

There other security issues such as not using a random iv (or any) with CBC mode which is the default for CCCrypt