# How to build framework more securely in iOS

Tags: ios

I am trying to create a iOS framework which would be used by multiple team in my concern. I want to make sure that the framework is more secured and will not be hacked by anyone. Please give me some steps/way to build the framework in a secured way. (Could be usage of cryptography/passcode).

Thanks in advance.

Comment: use encryption concept , for e.g see this https://code.tutsplus.com/tutorials/securing-and-encrypting-data-on-ios--mobile-21263

Comment: some another example https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1400246/aes-encryption-for-an-nsstring-on-the-iphone

Comment: Please explain "will not be hacked"? Hacked how? Who is the attacker, how skilled, the motivation, the financial loss due to a hack? IOW what isw thew threat model?

Comment: Let me explain the context more clearly. I am developing a framework which has details about the certain product(secured) and I would share it with some developers. I do not want all the users to use every methods in the framework. I want to encapsulate certain features and do not want any developer who downloaded the framework to see all its method. Is there a way to do it.